# Meaning of "as one would in a democracy"

Tags: meaning

When I was reading the following sentence, I stuck and could not understand the meaning of the sentence:

> As one would in a democracy, one looks to the requirements of all beings.

Is there any case that "would" becomes the main verb, not a modal verb? May I ask you to explain what the above sentence means?

Comment: One looks to the requirements of all beings as one would (normally do that) in a democracy.

Comment: What do you intend to communicate in a version where *would* is the main verb?

Comment: Stuck out? You need to proof and correct.